# Gem integration tests fail with jQuery not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, poltergeist

I have a gem called "**fantastic**" with a *dummy app* inside to test. When running the dummy app, everything works well.

However, when I run the tests, unit tests works fine, but integration tests (**Capybara + Poltergeist**) fail with the message:

> Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'jquery' with type
>   'application/javascript'.
>
> Checked in these paths:
>
> /fantastic/spec/dummy/app/assets/images,
>   /fantastic/spec/dummy/app/assets/javascripts,
>   /fantastic/spec/dummy/app/assets/stylesheets,
>   /fantastic/app/assets/javascripts,
>   /fantastic/app/assets/stylesheets,
>   /fantastic/vendor/assets/javascripts

Some of my files:

***fantastic.gemspec***

```
# ...
s.add_development_dependency "capybara"
s.add_development_dependency "poltergeist"
s.add_development_dependency "jquery-rails"
# ...
```

***spec/dummy/app/assets/javascripts/application.js***

```
//= require jquery // Error is produced in this line
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require fantastic
//= require_tree .
```

The thing is that when running **rails server** everything works fine, and jQuery is loaded properly (I tested it in the browser's console).

Any idea of what's happening on tests?

**EDIT**

I tried creating a custom `Capybara.app`:

**spec/spec_helper.rb**

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = 'test'
# Require dummy Rails app
require File.expand_path("../../spec/dummy/config/environment", __FILE__)

require 'database_cleaner'
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'capybara/poltergeist'

# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
# in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
Dir["#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/support/**/*.rb"].each {|f| require f}

require 'capybara/dsl'

Capybara.app = Rack::Builder.new do
  map "/spec/dummy/" { run Rails.application }
end.to_app

Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, {js_errors: false})
end
Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # If true, the base class of anonymous controllers will be inferred
  # automatically. This will be the default behavior in future versions of
  # rspec-rails.
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!
end
```

Given the dummy app is in `spec/dummy/` folder.

And this is the error I get when I run the tests

> Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_content "Users"
>          expected to find text "Users" in "Not Found: /users". (However, it was found 1 time using a case insensitive
>   search.)
>        # ./spec/features/record_updated_spec.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in '

Comment: Due to the unusual location of your app it’s possible the apps root isn’t be correctly detected. You may need to set a custom `Capybara.app` - see how Capybara defines the default - https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/rails.rb

Comment: @ThomasWalpole Thanks for your help, but I still can't make it work. I've just added more info, having used your input, can you take a look at my edit please?

Comment: Is this a publically accessible repo?  (I don’t see a gem called fantastic in rubygems.org)

Comment: It's not a public repo, and I cannot publish it because it's from work. Is there any other file I can share to make it easier?

Comment: Not that I can think of, if it was accessible I was going to try it and debug a bit.

Comment: If you can create a repo, with the same setup but none of your companies code, that replicates your issue I’ll look at that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what ended up fixing the issue.

```
module Fantastic
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    require 'jquery-rails' # <-- this line

    isolate_namespace Megaphone
  end
end
```